# (Java - Spigot) I have a problem with my PlayerInteractEvent

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I just started to learn Spigot/Java and I have a problem with my PlayerInteractEvent. Every time I right-click or left-click a block (in Adventure Mode) this shows up.
I don't know what the Problem is, can you Guys help me?

This is my code:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        if (e.getItem().hasItemMeta() && e.getItem() != null){      
            
            if (e.getItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals("§b§lNavigator")) {
                p.openInventory(Main.CompassInventory);
                e.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }else{}
        
    }

}
```

and this is the error code:

```
[12:37:14 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to hub v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:305) ~[spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:226) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PlayerInteractManager.interact(PlayerInteractManager.java:463) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:724) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PacketPlayInBlockPlace.a(PacketPlayInBlockPlace.java:50) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PacketPlayInBlockPlace.a(PacketPlayInBlockPlace.java:80) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PacketHandleTask.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.z(MinecraftServer.java:696) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.z(DedicatedServer.java:316) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.y(MinecraftServer.java:634) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:537) [spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack.hasItemMeta()" because the return value of "org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent.getItem()" is null
        at me.Items.Interact.onInteract(Interact.java:15) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:301) ~[spigot-18.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to switch the statements in the if, because you first have to check if the item is null before you  operate on it. If you operate on null you get this exception.
The "&&" works clever, so if the statement on the left of it is false then it does not check the other statement on the right.
Further you should check if the ItemMeta is null.

```
    @EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    if (e.getItem() != null && e.getItem().getItemMeta() != null && e.getItem().hasItemMeta()){      
        
        if (e.getItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals("§b§lNavigator")) {
            p.openInventory(Main.CompassInventory);
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }else{}
    
}
```